# How to pass structure to function in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I created structure **Route.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

struct Route {
    string startPoint;
    string endPoint;
    int number;
};
```

and I need to pass this structure to function. I used reference:

```
void CreateRoute(Route &route)
{
  int start = rand() % 10;
  int end = rand() % 10;

  if (start == end)
  {
    while(true)
    {
      end = rand()%10;
      if(end != start) break;
    }
  }

  route.startPoint = SetPoint(start);
  route.endPoint = SetPoint(end);
  route.number = SetNumber();
}
```

but it seems the using of pointers is the better way to do it, but I don't know how to use pointers for it?

Comment: Why do you think you should use pointers? I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: "Better" is clearly subjective, but you might also consider making `Route` the return type.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: @juanchopanza Because I have read the using of poiners is more powerful way to do it.

Comment: @Heidel no, that is just plain wrong. You would use a pointer if there is a chance the input could be null. That's about it.

Comment: In this case, I would just have the function make a new object and retrurn it. Copy can be optimized by move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, why aren't you simply returning a newly constructed object?

```
struct route
{
    std::string start_point;
    std::string end_point;
    int number;
};

route make_random_route()
{
    route r;

    int start = std::rand() % 10;
    int end = std::rand() % 10;

    while ( start == end) {
        end = std::rand() % 10;
    }

    r.start_point = make_point(start);
    r.end_point = make_point(end);
    r.number = make_number();

    return r;
}
```

Its trivial, and with move there is no copy.

Comment: Yes, by now I changed my all function and made `Route` the return type, `Route CreateRoute()`.

Answer (score 2):

`but it seems the using of pointers is the better way to do it`

One of the reasons C++ has references to begin with is to get around the hassle of dealing with pointers, arrows and lots of parentheses.

You could easily convert it to use a pointer type, but the ref type is just cleaner.

```
void CreateRoute(Route* route);
```

would be your declaration, and you would call it using

```
Route route;
CreateRoute(&route);
```

Comment: You don't need to call `new` at all. That will just add to the confusion.

Comment: It doesnt work if I call it using `CreateRoute(&route[i]);` (I need to pass member of array) but it works if I call it using `CreateRoute(route[i]);`

Comment: You changed the function definition to use arrows instead of dots, right?

Comment: By now I changed my all function and made `Route` the return type, `Route CreateRoute()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must improve your C++ basis. Below is my simple answer.

```
void CreateRoute(Route *route)
{
if (route == NULL)
    return;

int start = rand()%10;
int end = rand()%10;

if (start == end)
{
    while(true)
    {
        end = rand()%10;
        if(end != start) break;
    }
}

route->startPoint = SetPoint(start);
route->endPoint = SetPoint(end);
route->number = SetNumber();
}
```

Comment: While correct, this does nothing to dispel OP's strange notions about passing a pointer in the first place.